# Can I console.log from inside a click event in Edge Animate?

Tags: adobe-edge

I am trying to work out why my console.log command throws an event handler error when I put it into a click event.

My Javascript is not good enough to know if this is specific to Edge, or a more global JS thing.

Here is my code:

```
(function($, Edge, compId){
    var Composition = Edge.Composition,
        Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for  commonly used Edge classes

//Edge symbol: 'stage'
(function(symbolName) {
    Symbol.bindSymbolAction(compId, symbolName, "creationComplete", function(sym, e) {
       // insert code to be run when the symbol is created here
       var want = true;
       console.log(want);
    });

   //Edge binding end

   Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Rectangle}", "click", function(sym, e) {
      // insert code for mouse click here
      console.log(want);
   });

  //Edge binding end
})("stage");

//Edge symbol end:'stage'

})(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-26284910");
```

The first `console.log` after creationComplete works fine, the next one in the click event does not work, and I have no idea why. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you properly indent your code you'll notice that `want` was defined within inner function scope and was not accessible from within click handler.

```
(function($, Edge, compId){
    var Composition = Edge.Composition,
        Symbol = Edge.Symbol; // aliases for  commonly used Edge classes

//Edge symbol: 'stage'
(function(symbolName) {
    var want;
    Symbol.bindSymbolAction(compId, symbolName, "creationComplete", function(sym, e) {
       // insert code to be run when the symbol is created here
       want = true; //you still can set its value
       console.log(want);
    });

   //Edge binding end

   Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "${Rectangle}", "click", function(sym, e) {
      // insert code for mouse click here
      console.log(want); // but now it is accessible from within this function
   });

  //Edge binding end
})("stage");

//Edge symbol end:'stage'

})(window.jQuery || AdobeEdge.$, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-26284910");
```